# What is the difference between 经营模式vs。商业模式

Tags: vocabulary

I'm trying to figure out if there's a difference between  经营模式and 商业模式。 Right now, I'm writing a business case  （商业案例） and I'm trying to figure out which of these two would be the better title for a section of the case.

Thanks for the help!

Stephen

Comment: many examples at jukuu: e.g.  商业模式 business model，经营模式 operation mode, pattern of management

Comment: Like other answers and comments said, 商业模式 is what do you do and how do you make money e.g. ads vs. licensing, one-time fee vs. subscription etc. 经营模式 is how the business strategy is implemented e.g. high QOS high profit vs. bulk-cheap strategy.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is the scope besides their definitions. Business models can be very different, say between service and manufacturing. But operation model could be the same for different businesses, say retail stores for car parts and used furniture. Operation model could have bigger scope like network of dealerships, but it's somewhat defined by the business model - selling cars.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I would say they are the same, probably due to different translators. But 经营 sounds more like management and 商业 sounds more like business. I don't think there's an actual difference. I did found an article addressing the difference, but it's not a serious article. Stick with 商业 if you want a direct translation of "business model".

Answer (score 0):

简单来说经营模式可能适用于一些小一点的公司或者店面，比如一个小卖部的经营模式，一个小工厂的经营模式，但是商业模式往往用来形容一些大公司，比如某某集团，或者比较前沿的创业公司，总结一下，经营模式比较接地气，而商业模式让人感觉比较高端，上档次，其实本质差不多

Answer (score 0):

I come from Taiwan.
经营模式and 商业模式 is different!
经营 means a person , a group or a company used a method to treat itself!
But 商业 means transaction with different person,group or company!
So I think your case talk about only one company use 经营!
But if you talk about the mod of the transaction from the different company that you can use 商业!

經營是一總方法,是對內的,不管是公司,團體或個人!
換句話說:經營是用一個方法來規範公司,團體或者是自己!

而商業是對外的,要構成一個商業行為,至少要兩個不同的族群!
商業是用一些技術或者手段來達到自己的目的!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at the difference is to think operation model as tactics - how to do certain things in certain ways; business model as strategy - what to do in which area and what time and how much by whom sort of things.